# computation theory in coq

Tags: coq, computation-theory

2 subgoals
x, y : nat
H : x + 0 = y + 0

```
but after that I don't know how to to get rid of 0 in H.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's true that on paper you would simply conclude because `x + 0 = x`. Well, in Coq you have to prove it because addition is left-biased (it computes by looking up its first argument).

I would suggest proving first that

```
forall n, n + 0 = n
```

Comment: do you mean create a new theorem to prove n + 0 = n and then use rewrite?

Comment: yes, that's what he means.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
Theorem ex9: forall x y n, x + n = y + n -> x = y.
Proof.
 intros.
 induction n as [| n' IH].
 - rewrite add_0_r in H.      (* replace x + 0 with x *)
   rewrite add_0_r in H.      (* replace y + 0 with y *)
   assumption.
 - apply IH.                  (* replace x=y with x+n' = y+n' *)
   rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in H. (* replace x + S n' with S (x + n') *)
   rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in H. (* replace y + S n' with S (y + n') *)
   apply S_injective in H.    (* drop both S constructors *)
   assumption.
Qed.
```